# Do we need the God tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't think the tag "god" is adding anything to this site.  It could be removed from most of the questions I've looked at without losing any info. We have instead more specific tags like "nature-of-god", which I think are a much better way to go. Can I suggest we remove it, and use more-specific tags instead?

Comment: The [tag:jesus] tag might have this same argument.

Answer (score 8):

You are correct. That tag is relatively meaningless and a more specific tag should be used. We have

- [nature-of-god](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nature-of-god)
- [kingdom-of-god](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-of-god)
- [questioning-god](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/questioning-god)

and  we should probably add a couple of others that are more specific and should replace [god](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god)